# Explanation for variable performance of Android Room query

Tags: android-room

Preface: I understand that on a computer all kinds of things happen at random times. So profiling a method has to be repeated enough to get an average.

That said, I am a bit puzzled by the performance result of an Android Room query. I ran an Android room query multiple times. The average execution time is 26 ms. That's in line with my expectation. However, sometimes the query finishes in 0ms. Other times, it takes 117ms. That spread of duration surprises me.

How can the query sometimes by that instantaneous?

How can it be that slow sometimes? (I have to do a few queries. The sum is sometimes so slow that it affects performance of my app. Performance would be fine if they were more or less the average.)

The test environment is an emulator on beefy Alienware computer with many cores only running the test (and general background operating system noise).

Here are the execution times for 10 runs:

- 30ms
- 0ms
- 3ms
- 0ms
- 117ms
- 41ms
- 3ms
- 12ms
- 38ms
- 21ms

Why is the spread so much for Android Room queries?

Can I make more of them execute within 0ms?

Is there a way to near guarantee that they'll execute within 50ms? (That's what I'd need for my app to perform decently well.)

Should I dump Android Room and do my own queries?

Comment: Are you using live data or RxJava observables?

Comment: I'm simply using a dao (Room class that's annotated with @Dao) to query the database.

Comment: What is the return type of your dao query method?

Comment: It's a custom type annotated with @Entity. Maybe this is related. Over time my test suite runs slower. It completes within a handful of seconds at first. After a few runs, it takes 5-10 more time until I restart the emulator. When I try to profile where the time is spent, it's spent inside of sqlite code, not Android Room code.

Comment: What I was getting at is if your entity is `Foo`, are you returning `Foo` or `Flowable<Foo>`? But if you've determined that the slowdown is in sqlite, my guess that it might have something to do with thread scheduling is probably wrong.

Comment: Can you give me a hint or link to how to analyze/understand thread scheduling problems with sqlite? An observation that I made is that the query complexity doesn't seem to impact the measured times. (Obviously, giant full table scan queries will.) I analyzed the sqllite execution plans. I tried multi-table queries. They don't seem to have an effect on observed execution time. Most of the sqlite query execution seems to be spent in overhead, not the actual data reading based on my rudimentary profiling.

Comment: I don't know much about SQLite threads.  My suspicion was that it had something to do with RxJava (i.e., observing on a different thread) but it sounds like that is not the case.